# Tomcat is not shutting down

Tags: java, tomcat

I am unable to shutdown tomcat. When I do ./shutdown.sh, I don't see any error, but the process still seems to be running. When I kill the process (kill -9), the process gets killed. After this, if I do a startup, and shutdown again, I see the same problem. How do I gracefully shut it down? Why is this happening in the first place? Please help me.

```
devServer:bin dev$ ps -ef|grep tomcat
  501 34933     1   0 11:24PM test    0:02.02 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/dev/admin/runtime/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/dev/admin/runtime/endorsed -classpath /Users/dev/admin/runtime/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/dev/admin/runtime/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/Users/dev/admin/runtime -Dcatalina.home=/Users/dev/admin/runtime -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/dev/admin/runtime/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
  501 34982 33786   0 11:45PM test    0:00.00 grep tomcat
devServer:bin dev$ ./shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/dev/admin/runtime
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/dev/admin/runtime
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/dev/admin/runtime/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/dev/admin/runtime/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/dev/admin/runtime/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
devServer:bin dev$ ps -ef|grep tomcat
  501 34933     1   0 11:24PM test    0:02.03 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/dev/admin/runtime/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/dev/admin/runtime/endorsed -classpath /Users/dev/admin/runtime/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/dev/admin/runtime/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/Users/dev/admin/runtime -Dcatalina.home=/Users/dev/admin/runtime -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/dev/admin/runtime/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
  501 34992 33786   0 11:45PM test    0:00.00 grep tomcat
devServer:bin dev$
```

Also, I see my catalina.out is rather too short. There is no port number info getting written to it at all. This is all I see everytime I startup.

```
Feb 15, 2014 11:24:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
```

Here is my log file -

```
devServer:logs dev$ cat catalina.2014-02-15.log 
Feb 15, 2014 11:24:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
```

Something seems to be terribly messed up. I can't understand what. Please advise.
I am running tomcat 7.0.50 on Mac OS.

Comment: Is there any application deployed in this tomcat? Or is it a fresh tomcat downloaded from the tomcat official site? Also can you paste your complete logs ( both on tomcat startup and on tomcat shutdown )

Comment: I have tried changing the port, but no luck. When I try to <server IP>:port number in my browser, the page never loads, which basically means my tomcat never started up :(

Comment: I would like to see the logs. Kindly paste the startup/shutdown logs

Comment: Only my application is deployed in this tomcat. I am using a tomcat 7.0.50 template that we are using across all the applications in my company.But we are facing issues only on this server.

Comment: Do the same minimal logs show in the other servers as well? Or you get complete tomcat logs in the other servers.

Comment: I get complete logs. Of the pattern - ... INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
... INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]. Something seems very wrong on this server.

Comment: `kill -3` on the remaining pid might help the diagnostic

Comment: On the remaining pid?

Comment: @RC.I think its an incomplete tomcat instance, because according to the logs, `catalina` service is not getting started at all

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by incomplete tomcat instance? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @rickygrimes just `ps -ef` without the grep, look for tomcat, get the number in the PID column and run a `kill -3 the_number`, this will give you a java stacktrace that might help understanding what's wrong

Comment: I just did that. Didn't give me a java stack trace though.

Comment: When I do a ps -ef, grab the process id, and do kill -3, it is not killing the process. If I do ps -ef again, I still see the process running.

Comment: Okay I see a lot of messages in catalina.out now.

Comment: Updated the post. @RC - Can you please suggest what these messages mean?

Comment: @rickygrimes kill tomcat. clear all tomcat logs. start tomcat and post complete logs from startup. looks like tomcat instance is trying starting some app without success.

Comment: I killed it. Please read the entire post.

Comment: @rickygrimes you have to see `16.2.2014 10:29:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina` in catalina.out log file. if no, problem is with startup, no shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the logs, it is evident that tomcat is not starting up at all as it should be. I can advise a couple of other tests as well like to

1. Verify whether or not the ports are getting bound by the tomcat service or not. You can do this by issueing the command `netstat -tuplen` on the terminal and check to see if port 8080 is getting bound by the tomcat instance or not.
2. Check to see if you can ping the instance. Try to ping the tomcat instance from a local machine. Then try to ping the public ip of the server to verify whether that server is responding correctly or not
3. Verify that you have, infact, the complete tomcat template as is used by your other servers. Verify the tomcat installtion folder and compare it with the other tomcat templates as used in rest of your servers. Make sure all folders are there, all configuration (default tomcat config) files are present.
4. (Just a hunch) Verify read/write/execute privileges as well
5. Remove your application, shutdown tomcat, empty the logs, and then restart tomcat and re-deploy your application and then view the logs to see if you get some error

Point 3 seems more likely that you have an incomplete tomcat instance, so I advise you to make a copy of the tomcat instance used in any other server and use it in this server to make sure that the server environment is infact how it should be

Comment: Strangely on this server, all the ports are blocked. I checked the ports that are open using Open Network Utility, and configured the shutdown and the startup port based on the ports that are available. How do I verify 1? 2 - Yes, I can ping the instance. I am also able to telnet to the ports - telnet localhost <portNumber> 3. Yes, I have the complete template. I wouldn't copy only a portion of it. Like I said, it works perfectly fine on my other servers.

Comment: you can check it by starting tomcat, then get the process ID of tomcat and check to see if port 8080 is used up by the correct tomcat process ID

Comment: @DownVoter, I dont mind crticism, but atleast explain the reason for the downvote